# Open a modal on another modal with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog

I made a modal using Bootstrap, however I need a confirmation modal that goes above it. This second one will appear as a confirmation dialog for when one of the first modal's buttons are pressed.

This is roughly what my code looks like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      displayConfirmModal: false
    }
  }

  confirmModal () {
    return (
      <div ref={(ref) => { (this.modal = ref) }} className='modal fade' id='confirm' tabIndex={-1} role='dialog' aria-labelledby='GPA Modal'>
        <section>
          <h3>Are you sure of this?</h3>

          <button
          className='btn btn-danger'
          onClick={()=> doTheThing()}>
            Yes
          </button>
          <button
           className='btn btn-danger'
           onClick={()=> hideConfirmModal()}>
            No
          </button>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={(ref) => { (this.modal = ref) }} className='modal fade' id='main' tabIndex={-1} role='dialog' aria-labelledby='GPA Modal'>
          <section>
            <a className='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close' onClick={() => this.hideModal()}>close</a>
            <div className='frame'>
              <h1>My first modal</h1>

              <button
              className='btn btn-default'
              onClick={() => { this.setState({displayConfirmModal: true})}}>
                 Open confirmation modal
              </button>
            </div>
          </section>
      </div>
      { this.state.displayConfirmModal ? this.confirmModal() : null }
    </div>
    )
  }
```

As it is right now when I click on the `Open confirmation modal` button, it sets my `displayConfirmModal` state to true, but doesn't display the modal.

However, if I start the `displayConfirmModal` state on true, it does display it, and when I close it, it closes the whole thing.

How do I do this? And if so, is there a better alternative way of doing this?

Thanks!